# How can I create a collection of business objects from multiple elements in a XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to create a collection of business objects from the following xml document using .net 4.0/c#

```
    <WebServices ErrorFound="False" ServerDateTime="30/11/2010 14:58:58">
        <Results>
            <Users TotalResults="5">
                <UserName UserID="2">John</UserName>
                <UserName UserID="3">Dave</UserName>
                <UserName UserID="4">Jim</UserName>
                <UserName UserID="5">Bob</UserName>
            </Users>
        </Results>
    </WebServices>
```

This is the class I need to create

```
    public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }
```

Each of the Users child elements should be a new instance of the class.
So far I have this method which accepts an XmlDocument.

```
public static IEnumerable<User> GetUser(XmlDocument xmlDoc)
{
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlDoc.OuterXml));
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);

    var user = from u in doc.Descendants("WebServices").DescendantsAndSelf("Users")
               select new User()
               {
                   Name = u.Element("UserName").Value,
                   ID = int.Parse(u.Element("UserName").Attribute("UserID").Value)
               };

     List<User> userInstance = user.ToList();
     IEnumerable<User> users= from u in userInstance
                              select u;
     return users;

 }
```

This works fine as far as producing one instance of the object from the first child element is concerned but I am unsure as to how to create multiple instances from all the elements.
I need to be able to return a collection of the User objects eg `Collection<User> users = new Collection<User>()`

I could be barking up completely the wrong tree. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please do not use `new XmlTextReader()`. It's been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` instead.

Comment: Thanks, method updated to use XmlTextReader().

Comment: Performance wise: Do not use OuterXml and then a parser. This writes the entire document into a text and then parses it again - very expensive. If you really need to convert from XmlDocument to XDocument, then you can use for example CreateNavigator().ReadSubtree() to get an XmlReader over the XmlDocument and use that to load the XDocument. In general I would not try to use XDocument or LINQ to XML if the input is XmlDocument, instead I would use either XmlDocument API directly or XPath to do the same and avoid the conversion.

Comment: Thanks Vitek Karas I'll take a look at the performance issues you mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I finally figured out what was wrong with my code.
Instead of

```
var user = from u in doc.Descendants("WebServices").DescendantsAndSelf("Users")
        select new User()
        {
            Name = u.Element("UserName").Value,
            ID = int.Parse(u.Element("UserName").Attribute("UserID").Value)
        };
```

I now have

```
var user = (from u in doc.Descendants("UserName")
        select new Provider()
        {
            Name = u.Value,
            ID = int.Parse(u.Attribute("UserID").Value)
        });
```

the statement: `doc.Descendants("UserName")` basically produces an array of the UserName elements which can be iterated through, I can then directly access the value of that element and set it to my class properties.

Answer (score 1):

Using XPath you can write the code like this:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
} 

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string xml =
        "<WebServices ErrorFound='False' ServerDateTime='30/11/2010 14:58:58'>" +
            "<Results>" +
                "<Users TotalResults='5'>" +
                    "<UserName UserID='2'>John</UserName>" +
                    "<UserName UserID='3'>Dave</UserName>" +
                    "<UserName UserID='4'>Jim</UserName>" +
                    "<UserName UserID='5'>Bob</UserName>" +
                    "</Users>" +
            "</Results>" +
        "</WebServices>";

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);

    var users = from userNameElement in doc.SelectNodes("/WebServices/Results/Users/UserName").OfType<XmlElement>()
                select new User
                {
                    Name = userNameElement.InnerText,
                    ID = Int32.Parse(userNameElement.GetAttribute("UserID"))
                };

    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(user.ID.ToString() + ": " + user.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's also an option.